# I can't connect to Contentful with Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, contentful

When I try to connect to Contentful with Gatsby, I get this error message :

```
Starting to fetch data from Contentful
info Fetching default locale

 ERROR 

Accessing your Contentful space failed.
Try setting GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true to see if we can serve from cache.

Used options:
spaceId: "*******ed"
accessToken: "*******ed"
host (default value): "cdn.contentful.com"
environment (default value): "master"
downloadLocal (default value): false
localeFilter (default value): [Function]
forceFullSync (default value): false
pageLimit (default value): 100
useNameForId (default value): true

not finished source and transform nodes - 0.320s
```

My code in gatsby-config.js :

```
module.exports = {

  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby`,
    siteUrl: `http://localhost8000`,
    author: '****',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: ${`process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID`},
        accessToken: ${`process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN`},
        // My code only works with this syntax ${`...`}
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

I saw [Brent Arias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284758/brent-arias)'s response on this page: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892938/ Accessing your Contentful space failed with gatsby-source-contentful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892938/accessing-your-contentful-space-failed-with-gatsby-source-contentful). He overwrites and creates the contentful space, and locally relaunches the starter script "rg-portfolio" which natively contains a contentful configuration. It also refers to a "contentful-data.json" file in the starter.

I use the "hello world" starter, so I added the gatsby-source-contentful plugin myself, and it didn't create a "contentful-data.json" file, and I don't see anything about this json file on the [plugin's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/).
I deleted and recreated my contentful space, then I reinstalled the plugin, but it still doesn't work ...

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the Contentful part in your gatsby-config.js? :)

Comment: Your `gatsby-config` should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/antibland/128e20647acd5dec07adeaf85916f86c)

Comment: @AndyHoffman Yes I tried to write the code this way, but I don't know why it didn't work. I had an error message because it did not recognize it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed an issue in how you're doing string literals.

Change this:

```
spaceId: ${`process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID`},
accessToken: ${`process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN`},
```

Into either this (**recommended**):

```
spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
```

Or this:

```
spaceId: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}`,
accessToken: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
```